# node-sass imports and partials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sass

I'm building a MEAN app and I'm using [node-sass](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass) middleware to compile my .SCSS before express servers the static .CSS files and I'm currently experiencing a pretty annoying bug.

My middleware is set up like so:

```
app.use(sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/app/views/',
    dest: __dirname + '/app/views/',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/views'));
```

In my main.scss I've got `@imports` that serve sass from my /partials directory. But to see these changes in the browser, I have to save (cmd+s) the current working .scss file and then hit save (cmd+s) in main.scss and only when I hit save in main.scss do the changes render in the browser.

Anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Just answered a similar questions about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36833614/389014